# Is there a way to know that a custom notification is about to be shown?

Tags: android

I have a custom notification which is always available to the user (not a notification for a specific event) and should present up-to-date data.
Is there a way to know the notifications screen is being shown so I can update my notification data just at this time, instead of polling new data periodically?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should just call the notify method of NotificationManager when you want to do an update with the id of your notification it is just the way you should be doing to update your notification, its not called polling new notifications everytime. Are you using the default notification system on android?

Comment: Hi, I meant if I have a non-cancelable notification which shows status of an application, not a per-single-event notification

Comment: Thanks for your answers. However what I meant is do I have a way to know that the notification is about to be shown (e.g. user pulls down the notification area)?

Answer (score 0):

Details using the notification manager:

Set up your initial message. Then do your first notification:

```
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);
    notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(GC.DATABASE_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Change the text for the contentText to the new information. Then use the following to update the notification:

```
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle, contentText, contentIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(GC.DATABASE_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

If the notification bar is expanded, the message area will update. There is no need to close and reopen the notification bar.

The text area of the display is limited in size horizontally. Not much text can be displayed. This is out of the developers guide.

If you want to display a progress bar or more text than in the normal drop down display, you have to customize the notification. See the developers guide. It's very straight forward.

Comment: I use a global constant class in my projects. The GC.DATABASE_NOTIFICATION_ID is a public integer value in the class. It is defined as 'public final static int GC.DATABASE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 101;